# Use product list template with my own product collection?

Tags: magento2, products

I already have a products collection and an empty page, how would I load the products list layout and use my own products collection?

### EDIT:

Better explanation hopefully.   I have a form to select year, make, model, and then category, which works well.  I got a product collection, I just want to display the collection in a standard product listing using the currently loaded theme but the solution eludes me.

The Year, make model and associated products are stored in their own models.  I didn't see a good way to store them in standard magento attributes as most products have several combinations of year, make, models.

### EDIT2:

Got somewhere by adding this to my layout but by default it just shows all products.  Possible to change the products displayed in the block?

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="ymmResult" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml" />
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this page?

Comment: Basically I want to list specific products on a page using whatever is the currently default listing page.  I already have a collection of products, just need them displayed.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a category? You can embed category blocks on non-category pages, like in this tutorial: http://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/magento/display-products-homepage

Comment: Yeah, I didnt explain myself well enough I guess.  I created a custom extension that you can choose year make model, and category and it brings back products in a collection.  If I could just pass that collection into a category dynamically that would be great.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is an example module that will allow you specify a product collection for a customized product list element, which you should be able to adapt to your needs. It works by extending the `ListProduct` class to allow it's backing collection to be set dynamically.

File Structure:

```
app/code/AAllen/CustomProdList
|
|   registration.php
|   
+---Block
|   \---Product
|           CustomList.php
|           
+---Controller
|   \---Index
|           Index.php
|           
+---etc
|   |   module.xml
|   |   
|   \---frontend
|           routes.xml
|           
\---view
    \---frontend
        \---layout
                customprodlist_index_index.xml
```

`registration.php`

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'AAllen_CustomProdList',
    __DIR__
);
```

`CustomList.php` is where we extend `ListProduct` by overriding the `GetLoadedProductCollection` method and adding a method to set the product collection.

```
<?php

namespace AAllen\CustomProdList\Block\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class CustomList extends ListProduct
{
    public function getLoadedProductCollection()
    {
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }

    public function setProductCollection(AbstractCollection $collection)
    {
        $this->_productCollection = $collection;
    }
}
```

`Index.php` is an example of a controller where we set a product collection on the `CustomList` block which will be placed in the layout file.

```
<?php

namespace AAllen\CustomProdList\Controller\Index;


use AAllen\CustomProdList\Block\Product\CustomList;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends Action
{
    /** @var PageFactory */
    protected $pageFactory;

    /** @var  \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
    protected $productCollection;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    )
    {
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->productCollection = $collectionFactory->create();

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->pageFactory->create();

        // obtain product collection.
        $this->productCollection->addIdFilter(5); // do some filtering
        $this->productCollection->addFieldToSelect('*');

        // get the custom list block and add our collection to it
        /** @var CustomList $list */
        $list = $result->getLayout()->getBlock('custom.products.list');
        $list->setProductCollection($this->productCollection);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

`module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="AAllen_CustomProdList" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

`routes.xml` defines an example route where we want to display the product list.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="customprodlist" frontName="customprodlist">
            <module name="AAllen_CustomProdList"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

`customprodlist_index_index.xml` is the layout for the above route. This is where we place our block element as well as some child blocks which I copied from `catalog_category_view.xml`.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Custom Product List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="AAllen\CustomProdList\Block\Product\CustomList" name="custom.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
                <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as="default"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                           name="category.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>

                </block>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks so much!  It says I can award bounty in 38 minutes.

Comment: @Aaron Allen How to set layer navigation for this collection?

Comment: This works :) thanks! Although it does not show me the sidebar with the filters. But you saved me hours with this.

Comment: @Aaron Allen Thanks for this post. Could you please tell me that, how to add layered navigation in this page?

Comment: swatches are not showing...?

Comment: **Great answer!!! Well done**

Answer (score 0):

Only for complet your answer, if you want to show the swatches you have to call the block in `customprodlist_index_index.xml`

```
<block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml">
    <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" />
    <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/filter.phtml"/>
</block>
```

Comment: If you put this block it shows the navigation layer, yes, but it's not related with the custom product collection shown. Do you know how to do it properly?

Comment: @ElTête Did you found any solution to do that ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/365942/get-swatches-filter-for-a-custom-page-with-product-list