# Magento 2: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setProduct() on boolean

Tags: magento2, widget

I'm trying to update the product widget to show some custom product data like that

```
 <?= $block->getChildBlock('name-of-block')->setProduct($_item)->toHtml() ?>
```

while this code works fine on list.phtml in the CatalogWidget's grid.phtml it cannot set the product

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/261775/85907

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem was that I had to get the layout first, so the working code was

`<?= $block->getLayout()->getChildBlock('name-of-block')->setProduct($_item)->toHtml() ?>`

Answer (score 2):

Issue that `getChildBlock('name-of-block')`.

The **.phtml or file** where you have called `<?= $block->getChildBlock('name-of-block')->setProduct($_item)->toHtml() ?>` that block **does not have any child block of name** `'name-of-block'`.

Ensure that `name-of-block` child Block exits for that current block.

```
<?php if($block->getChildBlock('name-of-block')):?>
<?= $block->getChildBlock('name-of-block')->setProduct($_item)->toHtml() ?>
<?php endif;?>
```