# Magento 2 call list.phtml with custom collection

Tags: magento2, collection, list.phtml

I have custom collection in `$collection` I want to pass it to `list.phtml` so that I don't have to create listing UI again. I am trying to do this but it is not working

```
<?php
echo $this->getLayout()
                ->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct")
                ->setProductCollection($collection)
                ->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml")
                ->toHtml();
?>
```

Comment: Checkout this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148680/use-product-list-template-with-my-own-product-collection

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was possible in Magento 1.9 to pass product collection to list.phtml, but you cannot do this in Magento 2.

The proper way to do this is to create your own Block file

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/ProductList.php
```

Code will be:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class ProductList extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{

    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if ($this->_productCollection === null) {

            //Generate your collection here

            $this->_productCollection = $collection;
        }

        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
}
```

Now call list.phtml using your custom Block

```
echo $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock("Vendor\Module\Block\ProductList")
    ->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml")
    ->toHtml();
```

Comment: little bit lengthy criteria, but I will try this

Comment: Thanks. worked for me

Comment: Great, welcome. please vote on answer too if it is helpful to you

Answer (score 1):

Better solution to write your colection and add in above template such as

```php
   $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->setPageSize(3); // fetching only 3 products
        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct')
            ->setCollection($collection)
            ->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml")
              ->toHtml();
```