# How to get widget parameter in custom phtml or block?

Tags: magento2.3

I want to get specific widget configuration in phtml or block.

In that phtml/block i want to load custom product collection with filter using that widget data.

I want to create a same page like product listing(category page) after getting that collection.

I also referred below solution.

[Use product list template with my own product collection?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148680/use-product-list-template-with-my-own-product-collection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I used ObjectManager but using the below code you can convert.

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap     = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$instance      = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$state         = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$widgetCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Widget\Model\Widget\Instance');
//$data = $widgetCollection->load(instanceId);
$data = $widgetCollection->load('1');
echo "<pre/>";
print_r($data->getData());
```

Result
[image]

Comment: let me try once

Comment: Yes its working for me

Comment: Array
(
    [instance_id] => 169
    [instance_type] => Vendor\Customwidget\Block\Widget\CustomwidgetCollection
    [theme_id] => 5
    [title] => Deal Of The Week
    [store_ids] => 2
    [widget_parameters] => {"block_title":"\u0635\u0641\u0642\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0633\u0628\u0648\u0639","block_type":"best_deal","past_days":"1000","limit":"20","all_category":"1"}
    [sort_order] => 0
)

Answer (score 2):

use **parameters** in **widget.xml**

```
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="category_id" sort_order="10" visible="true" xsi:type="text">
            <label>124</label>
        </parameter>
    </parameters>
```

you can get this value in **.phtml** like

```
<?php echo $block->getData('category_id'); ?>
```

hope this will work for you.

Comment: will you please explain bit more in this?

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-widget/

Answer (score 0):

this link has how you can get it data from phtml
https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-widget/